# subquery with inner join on knex

Tags: knex.js

I'm trying to make a subquery with a query builder, but I did can't.

The original sql is:

```sql
SELECT sms.id, 
       sms.number, 
       Max(sms_detail.datetime) AS datahora,
        (SELECT Count(status) AS quantidade FROM sms_detail WHERE sms_detail.sms_id = sms.id AND sms_detail.status = 0)
FROM   sms AS sms 
       INNER JOIN sms_detail 
               ON sms.id = sms_detail.sms_id 
GROUP  BY sms.id, 
          sms.number
ORDER  BY datahora DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a subquery with a query builder, but I did can't.

This is one way to write subquery:

```
const subQuery = knex('subquerytable').where('foo', 'bar');

// main query
knex('sms').select('sms.foo', subQuery).innerJoin(...).
```

I'm not going to write complete solution for you. I hope this helps enough.